# Disproving statement of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

How can I disprove this statement:

If the sequence $(a_n+b_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ converges, then both $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ and $(b_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ converge.

Is this statement able to be disproved? I thought that if they were both convergent sequences, then the sum of the limits had to converge as well! Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: $a_n = (-1)^n$, and $b_n = (-1)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a divergent sequence and set $b_n = -a_n$. For example, $a_n = n$ and $b_n = -n$ will do.

Comment: And that doesn't converge to zero?

Comment: Take $a_n = n$ and $b_n = -n + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that if $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ are convergent sequences, then the sequence $(a_n+b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges. However, the question is asking you to ponder the converse: if the sum of two sequences converges, must each of the parts necessarily converge on their own? And the answer is no, as the above answers have pointed out.